# How to run vim with a color file from an uncommon place?

Tags: vim, bashrc

I try to make a bash alias like this :

```
alias vi='vim -u /path/to/conf/.vimrc'
```

It works well, but if I add the color file, it failed :

```
vim -u /path/to/conf/.vimrc -S /path/to/conf/colors/foobar.vim :
```

:

```
E185: Cannot find color scheme 'foobar'
```

I have in vimrc :

```
source /full/path/to/color/foobar.vim
color foobar
```

In my color/foobar.vim :

```
let g:colors_name = "foobar"

if &term=~ "xterm"
    set term=xterm-256color
endif
if &term=~ "linux"
    colorscheme default
else
    colorscheme foobar
endif
```

I can't put files on default ~/.vim dir, because I use a special config on servers when I'm not alone : I would like to have my own config when I source my user ~/.bashrc from root.